# Display boostrap banner if a session variable contain value

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, session

I wants to display a bootstrap banner in a page, only if a session variable contains a value and also wants to null the session variable if a user close that banner by clicking the 'x' mark. I tried the given code. It will display the banner fine. But the session will be updated into null automatically if i not click 'x' button. Please help me.

**Copied From Comment:**

```
<script> 
$(function(){ $('.payment-status').click(function(){ 
    var status = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('status_payment');?>'; '<?php $this->session->set_userdata('status_payment','');?>'; 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

**For Display Banner**(From Comments)

```
<?php $payment_status = $this->session->userdata('status_payment'); if ($payment_status && $payment_status<>'' ) { ?> <div class="alert alert-success fade in payment-status" id="payment-status"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a> <strong><?php echo $payment_status?></strong> </div> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question with your code you have tried.

Comment: <script>
 $(function(){
  $('.payment-status').click(function(){
   var status = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('status_payment');?>';
    
   '<?php $this->session->set_userdata('status_payment','');?>';
  });
 });
</script>  'status_payment' is my session index

Comment: @GugankumarP Click on edit button below tags

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: i can't pase all the code can i update one by one

Comment: <?php 
    $payment_status = $this->session->userdata('status_payment');
  if ($payment_status && $payment_status<>'' )
  {
 ?>

  
   <div class="alert alert-success fade in payment-status" id="payment-status">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
      <strong><?php echo $payment_status?></strong>
   </div>
   
        <?php 
              
                }
        ?>  this is for display banner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this

```
$status = $this->session->userdata('status_payment');

if(!empty($status))
{
    # your Success Message
}
else
{
    # just keep empty or Your Error Message
}
```